# I cannot SSH to my Linux EC2 Instance from My IP suggested by AWS. It works if incoming rule is set to ::0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am always facing the below problem......

**If I create a new RHEL (or any Linux) EC2 Instance without any modification of default VPC Setting or Network ACL or Route Table (RT is open for outbound 0.0.0.0/0 and connected to default IGW):**

- SSH will only work from my machine if I select 0.0.0.0/0.
- In security Group In bound rule is I add My IP. SSH does not work.

Note:

1. The Public IP is current. 103.75.162.205
2. AWS provided CIDR in My IP [103.75.162.202/32] contains my Public IP.

**So technically My IP should work, but it is not working or I never made it to work. What I am missing?**

Comment: Those two IP addresses are different. Are you going via a corporate network? Sometimes  corporate networks use proxies and route HTTP traffic different to SSH traffic. Therefore, it might appear to be coming from a different address.

Comment: Thank you John.
1. Which two IP Addresses? 103.75.162.205 and 103.75.162.202/32? If yes, 103.75.162.205 is part of above CIDR (kindly add if I am missing out things here).

2. No.This is not corporate network. I am trying to SSH from home to my AWS EC2 Instance and trying to avoid 0.0.0.0/0. And how can I check if TCP and HTTP traffic are being routed separately?

Comment: `103.75.162.202/32` means _only_ `103.75.162.202`. The `/32` only has a CIDR of one IP address. If you want to allow access from `103.75.162.205` then use a CIDR of `103.75.162.205/32`.

Comment: Yes, I cannot use my IP, it always gives /32 and I cannot change it to /24 or others....
Need to use Custom IP 103.75.162.202/24.
Tried with 103.75.162.202/31 it does not work...Next I realized in a CIDR initial IP is used by AWS, hence, I changed my CIDR to 103.75.162.198/24 and now it is working, both SSH and Apache HTTPD

Answer (score 4):

I recommend:

- Open `0.0.0.0/0`
- Connect via SSH
- Disconnect
- Connect again: The instance will show the IP address from which you most recently connected
- Use this displayed IP address in the Security Group

Sometimes corporate networks route HTTP traffic differently than SSH traffic due to proxies. The above steps will help you discover the address being used for SSH traffic.

Comment: Sounds great, but I cannot provide an unique IP. It always give a CIDR, and though my IP is part of that series,connectivity does not work. And if I add the IP only in next step it gives an error...
Public IP (Verified) 103.75.162.207
The source needs to be a CIDR block or a Security Group ID.

Comment: You can give the IP as a CIDR: `103.75.162.207/32`

Answer (score 1):

My Public IP is: **103.75.162.202**

- I cannot use My IP option in Security Group, it always gives /32 and
- I cannot change it to /24 or others... Need to use Custom IP
  103.75.162.202/24. Tried with 103.75.162.202/31 it does not work...
- **Next I realized in a CIDR initial IP is used by AWS, hence, I changed
  my CIDR to 103.75.162.198/24** and now it is working, both SSH and
  Apache HTTPD